# Enum cannot reference a type through an expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have model class:

```
namespace BazeProjekt.Models
{
    public class Radio
    {
        public enum and_or { OR, AND };
        public enum algoritam { fuzzy, normal };

    }
}
```

And there is my View:

```
@using Npgsql
@model BazeProjekt.Models.Radio

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Full and fuzzy text search</h1>
</div>

<h2>Search:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("upit")
    <input type="submit" value="Traži" />
}

@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.and_or, "OR")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.and_or, "AND")

<h2>SQL:</h2>

@Html.TextArea("sql",(string)ViewBag.query,10,100,null)

@{

    NpgsqlDataReader dr = (NpgsqlDataReader)ViewBag.tablica;
}

@if (dr != null)
{
    int cnt = 0;

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        <p>@Html.Raw(dr[0]) - [@dr[1]]</p>
        cnt++;
    }

    <p>Broj pronađenih filmova je: @cnt</p>
}
```

I wanted to have 2 radio buttons with options OR and AND, but compiler says that it cannot reference a type through an expression.

Error   1   'and_or': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'BazeProjekt.Models.Radio.and_or' instead  c:\Users\TranceFusion\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Baze Projekt\Baze Projekt\Views\Home\Index.cshtml   20  29  Baze Projekt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your enums separately and include a property for that enum in the model

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  OR,
  AND
}

public class Radio
{
  public MyEnum and_or { get; set; }
}
```

then in the view

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.and_or, "OR")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.and_or, "AND")
```